# element position in whole document

Tags: xslt

I have the following xml sample and I want to output "book #n name is xxx" for each book where n=1 to 5.  position() evaluates to 1,2,1,2,3 so I can't use that function.
Thanks.

```
<books>
  <cat>
    <book>a</book>
    <book>b</book>
  </cat>
  <cat>
    <book>c</book>
    <book>d</book>
    <book>e</book>
  </cat>
</books>
...
...
<xsl:template match="book">
<!-- I need expression to evaluate as:
book a = 1
book b = 2
book c = 3
book d = 4
book e = 5
-->
    <xls:variable name="idx" select="postition()"/>
    name of book #<xsl:value-of select="$idx"/> is <xsl:value-of select"."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
 count(preceding::book) +1
```

Do note, however, that if it is possible to have nested `book` elements, then the correct expression to use becomes:

```
 count(ancestor::book | preceding::book) +1
```

**Or one can use**: **[`<xsl:number>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#element-number)**

**Complete code**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="book">
   <xsl:value-of select=
   "concat('book ', ., ' = ', count(preceding::book) +1, '&#xA;')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<books>
  <cat>
    <book>a</book>
    <book>b</book>
  </cat>
  <cat>
    <book>c</book>
    <book>d</book>
    <book>e</book>
  </cat>
</books>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
book a = 1
book b = 2
book c = 3
book d = 4
book e = 5
```

---

**II. Using [`<xsl:number>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#element-number):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="book">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;book ', ., ' = ')"/>
   <xsl:number level="any" count="book"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**III. Using `position()` with a proper [`<xsl:apply-templates>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#element-apply-templates)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*/book"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="book">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;book ', ., ' = ', position())"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Explanation**:

The value of `position()` is the position of the current node in the node-list produced of the `<xsl:apply-templates>` that caused the selection of this template for execution. If we use the proper `<xsl:apply-templates>` then using `position()` *can* be OK.

Comment: Thanks, Dimitre.  Exactly what I was looking for. Now I have to look up preceding to see how it works ;)

Comment: @bretter, You are welcome. I edited this answer several times, so it may be possible that you haven't seen all three solutions. Yes, one would be interested to read about the `preceding` and about the `ancestor` axes, and also about the `<xsl:number>` instruction, the `<xsl:apply-templates>` instruction and about the `position()` function.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - interestingly, the first XSLT you provided (with `<xsl:value-of select = "concat('book ', ., ' = ', count(preceding::book) +1, '&#xA;')"/>`) does not produce the correct result with Expat. Why I'm using Expat, I do not know. :)

Comment: @ABach, I also don't know why you are using Expat :)